# How to display array elements passed into Handlebars file one by one on button click?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, templating-engine

Suppose, I have following array of objects successfully sent to handlebars file from my express server:

```
[       
    {
        "name": "Jon",
        "isPositive": true 
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Cercei",
        "isPositive": false
    }
]
```

Each time when my button gets clicked, I want to show next element of the array on my view. Is it possible with handlebars? Or do I need something more complex like Vue.js to solve this problem? Here is simple pseudocode I would like to achieve:

```
<head>
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(() => {
            var index = 0; 
            var currentCharacter = getCurrentCharacter(); 
            start();
        });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <h3 id="name"></h3>
    <p id="someInfo"> </p> 

    <button onclick="next()">Next</button>

    <script>        
        function getCurrentCharacter() {
            /// somehow access array of objects sent from server
            var myCharacters = {{characters}}; // {} used because of handlebars 
            var character = myCharacters[index];
            index += 1; 

            return character;
        }

        function start() {
            document.getElementById("name").textContent = currentCharacter.name;

            /// as you see here, I change my UI based on current object fields/attributes
            if (currentCharacter.isPositive) {
                document.getElementById("someInfo").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("someInfo").textContent = "Some text here";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("someInfo").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }

        function next() {
            currentCharacter = getCurrentCharacter();
            start();
        }
   </script>
</body>
```

Is it possible to have such a logic with handlebars or other templating languages? If they are not build for these purposes, please recommend me another way to solve this problem.

Comment: I think Handlebars is sufficient for this task.

Comment: What are you struggling with, specifically? There's no need to use Vue for a simple task. You can accomplish what you want with just plan JavaScript.